# How to call a method from activity to fragment android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to call this fragment from the changelistner, i recently change the activity SearchBar to a fragment. Its giving an error Inconvertible types.

```
 public class CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener  implements TextWatcher {

public static final String TAG = "CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener.java";
Context context;

public CustomAutoCompleteTextChangedListener(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                              int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence userInput, int start, int before, int count) {

    // if you want to see in the logcat what the user types
    Log.e(TAG, "User input: " + userInput);


    SearchBar mainActivity = ((SearchBar) context);

    // query the database based on the user input
    mainActivity.item = mainActivity.getItemsFromDb(userInput.toString());

    // update the adapater
    mainActivity.myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mainActivity.myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mainActivity.item);
    mainActivity.myAutoComplete.setAdapter(mainActivity.myAdapter);

}

}
```

It's giving an error on the line 
SearchBar mainActivity = ((SearchBar) context);

Answer (score 0):

Since now `SearchBar` is a fragment, you cannot access it the way you are doing it. You have to find it using tag name -

```
 SearchBar frag = (SearchBar) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(<tag_name>);
 if (profileDetailsFragment != null && frag.isAdded()) {
            frag.getItemsFromDb(userInput.toString());
 }
```

Where `<tag_name>` will be the name of the tag with which you instantiated your fragment.